# Analogue "recognize" in new Router 3.0

Tags: angular, angular-routing

There is a similar feature in the new router? How to make the same with help new Router?

```js
 this._router.recognize(x).then((data) => {
        if (!data) return;
        let id: string = data.component.params['id'];
        let name: string = data.component.params['name'];
    });
```

I need recognize route and get params.

Comment: What does `recognize` do?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer url

Comment: url what? . . . . . .

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer current route's url, for example.

Comment: So just use ActivatedRoute.

Comment: @KamilMyśliwiec no. I parse it centralized, in one module.